# Error al hacer una consulta sql TRUNCATED INCORRECT DOUBLE value"" ERROR 1292

Tags: sql

**Álbumes de U2 de los años 1980 a 1990 que pertenezcan al género Pop-Rock**

```
SELECT titulo, fecha
FROM albumes,generos
WHERE albumes.cod_album=generos.cod_genero AND fecha>1980 AND fecha<1990 AND genero IN(SELECT genero IN(1)From generos)
ORDER BY fecha;
```

*Necesito hacer esta consulta desde mi localhost y no entiendo este error*

[image: Error TRUNCATE 1292]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**He publicado mi base de datos y una imagen del error.**
*La consulta debe tener algún error de sintaxis pero no consigo solucionarlo.*
**Cualquier duda no dudéis en contarme.**

Comment: cod_genero que tipo de parametro es? ¿Es double?

Comment: cod_genero es clave primaria tipo Btree, Me ha funcionado al hacer la consulta mediante álbumes_genero, SELECT titulo, fecha
FROM albumes, albumes_generos
WHERE albumes.cod_album=albumes_generos.cod_genero AND fecha>1980 AND fecha<2020 AND cod_genero IN(3,7)
GROUP BY fecha;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NainThink, en tu pregunta inicial estás haciendo una consulta de un JOIN entre albumes y generos sin la tabla intermedia albumes_generos.
Además, haces referencia a álbumes de U2 y no lo tienes en cuenta en la consulta.
Mis solución sería una de las siguientes, en función de si lo haces sobre el nombre de grupo y género, o si se hace sobre los códigos de grupo (por ejemplo 100 para **U2**) y género (por ejemplo 5 para **Pop-Rock**):

Caso 1:

```
SELECT alb.cod_album, alb.titulo, alb.fecha
FROM albumes alb 
    JOIN grupos ON alb.cod_grupo=grupos.cod_grupo 
    JOIN albumes_generos ON alb.cod_album=albumes_generos.cod_album 
    JOIN generos ON albumes_generos ON albumes_generos.cod_genero=generos.cod_genero 
WHERE 
    grupos.nombre="U2" 
    AND generos.genero="Pop-Rock"
    AND fecha>1980 AND fecha<1990
```

Caso 2:

```
SELECT alb.cod_album, alb.titulo, alb.fecha
FROM albumes alb 
    JOIN albumes_generos ON alb.cod_album=albumes_generos.cod_album 
WHERE 
    alb.cod_grupo=100
    AND albumes_generos.cod_genero=5
    AND fecha>1980 AND fecha<1990
```

Answer (score 0):

**Esta query funciona en mi base de datos.**

```
SELECT titulo, fecha
FROM albumes, albumes_generos
WHERE albumes.cod_album=albumes_generos.cod_genero AND fecha>1980 AND fecha<2020 AND cod_genero IN(3,7)
GROUP BY fecha;
```

Sin embargo sigo sin entender ese error, pero la solución ha sido hacer la consulta mediante el código género en la tabla albumes_genero y ya no salta error y hace la consulta de forma exitosa.

Finalizado ejercicio de consulta.
[image: Resultado de Query]